# MacBook Pro 2016 going to sleep after one minute no matter what my settings are

Tags: macbook-pro, power-management

My energy saver preferences are as follows:

[image]

However, no matter what I set the slider to, my MacBook Pro is going to sleep after one minute. What is wrong here?

Comment: Are both the "Battery" and "Power Adapter" settings identical?

Comment: Yes. I have them both set on the third ticker.

Comment: Open the terminal, type `pmset -g`, and paste the output here

Comment: System-wide power settings:
Currently in use:
 standbydelay         10800
 standby              1
 womp                 1
 halfdim              1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 powernap             1
 gpuswitch            2
 networkoversleep     0
 disksleep            10
 sleep                0 (sleep prevented by iTunes)
 autopoweroffdelay    28800
 hibernatemode        3
 autopoweroff         1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         15
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1

Comment: Also ensure you do not have a magnet near the left or right side of the Mac. The Mac uses magnets in the display to put it to sleep when the display is closed. [link](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT203315)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first instinct would be to reset the SMC.

**Resetting the SMC**

To do this on your particular MBP, follow these steps:

1. Shut down your computer
2. Keep the power cable **plugged in**.
3. Press at the same time <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>control</kbd> 
   (on the left side of the keyboard) ***and*** the <kbd>power button</kbd>
4. Let go
5. Turn your computer back on with the power button.

Also, you should probably reset the NVRAM as well.

**Resetting the NVRAM on Late-2016 MacBook Pro models**

For all Late-2016 MacBook Pro models (with and without Touch Bar) follow these 
steps:

1. **Shut down your machine.** Yes, a full shut down, not just logging out.
2. **Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> *and then* immediately press the 
   <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> keys.**
3. **Keep these keys pressed down for at least 20 seconds!**
4. **Let go of the keys and let your Mac reboot normally.** 
   **Note:** When you log back in you ***may*** need to readjust some of your system 
   preferences (e.g. speaker volume, screen resolution, startup disk selection, time zone 
   information, etc).
   Let me know how you go.

**[EDIT - Screensaver]**

Since resetting the NVRAM and SMC have had no effect, perhaps you should check your Screensaver settings to see if it's kicking in after one minute? To check this:

- Go to Apple menu > System Preferences
- Select Desktop & Screen Saver
- Click on the Screen Saver tab
- Check when it is set to start

Comment: Strange, neither of these solutions seems to be working.

Comment: I've just edited my answer. If that doesn't help, when you say it's going to sleep after 1 minute, is it going to a full sleep or is it just preparing to sleep? That is, after one minute is it just dimming the screen and then going to full sleep after three minutes? Or is it doing something else? And, what happens if you change it to five minutes? Finally, what happens when you boot into Safe Mode (you can do this by holding down the Shift key during startup).

Comment: Ah, silly me! The screensaver was coming on after one minute.